# How to get an img tag with a class name from a link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I have a [search engine](http://sphider.eu/) which I have been playing with for some time now, and for some time now I wanted to add a new feature: display the article image when searching on my website. See example:

- [Searching for QTox - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/search.php?query=QTox&search=1)

I have some code that I have bin playing around with, but it doesn't work when there are [multiple links](http://www.eurobytes.nl/search.php?query=Ubuntu&search=1). Meaning it only displays the images of the first link. The engine has the entire code in a variable.

What I am trying to get is a php/js(jquery) code, that parses a link - provide by the search engine - in the `$url` variable, that it will search for the `a` tag within it, the `img` with the class name `article-image`. it then display it in the `a` tag with the id `searchimage`. Might be better to turn that in a class, but I'll rely on you guys on what is the better option.

**External link with the img**:

> ```
> <a class="article-image" title="Qtox" href="http://i.imgur.com/GePjpxg.png">
>   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GePjpxg.png" alt="Qtox">
> </a>
> ```

The search engine when founded more links, will use the same template, so the code has to be used again and again.

Here is the code I have so far that I have reused so far:

```
<?php
$tagName = 'img';
$articlimageclass = "article-image";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile("$url");

$linkimg = getTags($dom, $tagName);

?>
<?php
function getTags($dom, $tagName) {
     $linkimg = get_class($articlimageclass);

     $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $newDom = new DOMDocument;
     $newDom->formatOutput = false;

     $filtered = $domxpath->query("//$tagName");
     $i = 0;
     while( $myItem = $filtered->item($i++) ){
         $node = $newDom->importNode( $myItem, true );
         $newDom->appendChild($node);                
     }
     $linkimg = $newDom->saveHTML();
//     return "<b>$html</b>";     

     echo "$linkimg";
}
?>
```

I am novice in php and etc. So I hope some of you will help me on this!

Comment: Question, do you want to do this in PHP or JQuery? Both could work. Basically you examine the URL. If it contains `.jpg`, `.gif`, or `.png`, you could replace the title with an `<img>` tag. Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: @Twisty anything that works. I just need it to search the `a` tag with the css class `article-image`, and within it the img tag! I need that img tag!

Comment: So looking at your code again, where is `$url` defined? You want to search the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag. If it matches your criteria, you would replace the `innerHTML` of the `<a>` tag with an `<img>` that has a `src` attribute equal to the value of the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with `DOMDocument` at all so this is just a guess. You can modify your function a bit to do this:

```
function makeImageLink($dom, className) {
     $supported_image = array(
      'gif',
      'jpg',
      'jpeg',
      'png'
     );

     $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $newDom = new DOMDocument;
     $newDom->formatOutput = false;

     if(isset($className){
       $filtered = $domxpath->query("//a[class='$className']");
     } else {
       return false;
     }
     foreach($filtered as $a){
       $href = $a->getAttribute("href");
       $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($href, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Using strtolower to overcome case sensitive
       if (in_array($ext, $supported_image)) {
         $a->innerHTML = "<img src='$href'>";
       }
     }
}
```

To do this in JQuery (in the browser) it would be:

```
var a = $("a[class='article-image']");
var supportedImages = array('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png');
$.each(a, function(k, v)){
  var imgType = $(this).substring($(this).lastIndexOf("."));
  if(supportImages.indexOf(imgType)){
    $(this).html("<img src='" + $(this).attr('href') + "'>");
  }
}
```